# How can I run an integration test on code with Guice injections?

Tags: java, junit, dependency-injection, guice

I have a project that relies heavily on Guice injections. I've set up unit tests with JUnit, but I need to step through the code in a specific function when the dependencies aren't mocked.

It would be awesome to run a JUnit test. I'd just like to avoid manually creating all the dependencies, because the dependencies have their own dependencies and it goes on forever. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you show code for an example service object?

Comment: Look for Carlos Becker GuiceTestRunner.  I think it's not supported/maintained anymore, but it works.